# Which groups are being compared in this code?

Tags: linear-regression, stata, logistic-regression

I am running a linear and logistic regression in Stata and comparing an outcome between different race/ethnicity groups. This is an example of the user-defined coding I am using and I don't understand which group is being compared for each variable (x1,x2,x3). Could someone please help!!

**X1:**
generate x1 =  -.5 if race == 1

replace  x1 =   .5 if race == 2

replace  x1 = -1.5 if race == 3

replace  x1 =  1.5 if race == 4

**X2:**
generate x2 =  -1 if race == 1

replace  x2 =   1 if race == 2

replace  x2 =  -1 if race == 3

replace  x2 =   1 if race == 4

**X3:**
generate x3 =  1.5 if race == 1

replace  x3 =  -.5 if race == 2

replace  x3 =  1.5 if race == 3

replace  x3 = -2.5 if race == 4

Answer (score 0):

Given that `race` takes on values 1 2 3 4, we can examine the effects:

```
clear 
set obs 4 
gen race = _n 

generate x1 = -.5 if race == 1
replace x1 = .5 if race == 2
replace x1 = -1.5 if race == 3
replace x1 = 1.5 if race == 4

generate x2 = -1 if race == 1
replace x2 = 1 if race == 2
replace x2 = -1 if race == 3
replace x2 = 1 if race == 4

generate x3 = 1.5 if race == 1
replace x3 = -.5 if race == 2
replace x3 = 1.5 if race == 3
replace x3 = -2.5 if race == 4

reshape long x, i(race) j(which)
label define which 1 x1 2 x2 3 x3 4 x4
label val which which 

twoway connected x race, by(which, note("") row(1)) yla(-2.5(0.5)1.5, ang(h))
```

[image]

What in general is going on here -- or what specifically this has to do with linear and/or logistic regression -- is anyone's guess. Possibly  someone is playing with different representations of race as a predictor. Without more context there isn't even a statistical question to answer here, let alone a programming question.